# BottleNeck for SSD in my Laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, performance

I want to improve performance of my laptop have Core i5 3rd Gen, 12 GB Ram.

One solution is replacing HDD with SSD.But before doing that I want to ask you guys is there any potential bottleneck in laptop which can cause no speed gain or not the optimum gain even after the replacement.

What maximum storage drive speed a typical laptop can handle according to you guys?

Comment: What performance are you wanting to improve?

Answer (score 0):

The [SATA version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Revisions) can be the bottleneck, because with [SATA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_2.0_.283.C2.A0Gbit.2Fs.2C_300.C2.A0MB.2Fs.2C_Serial_ATA-300.29) you can only get around 200MB/s while with [SATA3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_3.0_.286.C2.A0Gbit.2Fs.2C_600.C2.A0MB.2Fs.2C_Serial_ATA-600.29) you can get 500MB/s.

So look in the documentation of your laptop which SATA version you use. But even with a SATA2 SSD the performance gain would be noticeable because of the slower access time of SSDs compared to HDDs.

Answer (score 0):

As your computer will be from on/after  2013 you would expect it to run SATA3, and you will get a substantial increase in performance - you don't need to worry about bottlenecks.

Even were it an ancient SATA2 interface you would still get 3 times the raw speed - and it would feel even faster because you are not waiting for the correct part of the disk to move under a head.

If your system is disk bound it will make a massive difference - probably similar to a new system.

Comment: ...and the system is probably disk bound.  Buy the SSD.